# scala test with POST

Tags: scala, mockito

does anyone knows how to see if a test is correct doing a comparison between the repository function (chirpsRepository.save) and the function I implemented in the api(api.saveChirp)??

The problem is that chirpsRepository.save is a void function and I dont know how I would be able to test that!!!

```
  "POST /api/chirps" should "return status Ok" in {
       new TestChirpsApi {
         println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
         println(api.saveChirp(NewChirp("John Doe message")))
         when(chirpsRepository.save(ChirpRecord(new ObjectId("503df1850364e1967b576e5d"), "My message is here"))).thenReturn("Ok")
         println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
         assert(api.saveChirp(NewChirp("John Doe message")) === "Ok")

      }
  }
```

Thanks for the help, if anyone knows about scala and mockito guides for testing I will be pleased to know it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `chirpsRepository.save()` is void doesn't actually matter - what you should be testing is whether that method is called at all.

So rather than trying to define mocked behaviour on it (with `when(...)`), you should be using the `verify()` method *after* calling `api.saveChirp()` to make sure it delegated correctly.

The [Mockito documentation](http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) is very thorough - once you understand which collaborators should be *mocked* and which should be *verified*, you should have no trouble.